# Open file without (really) locking it?

Tags: c#, .net, interop

Is it possible to open a file in a way that allows subsequent deletion/renaming of its parent folder?

I know you can do this:

```
File.Open("foo.bar", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read | FileShare.Delete)
```

Which will allow for the file to be deleted when the file handle is closed.  However, if it does not allow the parent folder to be deleted without error.

I couldn't find anything in the framework.  Have I overlooked something, or is there a native API I can interop to.

Note: I don't care if I get an exception when using the stream of the deleted file.  In fact that would be ideal.

**UPDATE:**

So the most promising idea was the [Hardlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648939/open-file-without-really-locking-it/649372#649372), however I just can't make it work.  I still end up with Access Denied when i try to delete the parent directory.  Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool CreateHardLink(string lpFileName, string lpExistingFileName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string hardLinkPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
        string realPath = @"C:\foo\bar.txt";
        if (CreateHardLink(hardLinkPath, realPath, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            using (FileStream stream = File.Open(hardLinkPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete | FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                Console.Write("File locked");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            File.Delete(hardLinkPath);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("LastError:{0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with an NTFS you can create another hardlink to the file in a temporary location, you'll avoid the file copy overhead, and the first link should still be deletable (either the file itself or a containing directory) without effecting the second.

Comment: Hmmm, This seemed very promising, however I still get the error when i deleted the parent folder.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Hard links should be identical to the original file, that is, there isn't really a concept of a "main" pointer to the file, they all work identically. (it adds another directory pointer) I haven't personally used them in this exact situation, but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can come up with, is to copy the file to a temporary scratch location.  Then, open the temp file, and delete it when I'm finished.

Comment: Sounds like something I'd do.  Maybe you can copy to memory if the file is small enough?

Comment: yeah, we are doing that now, but there are lots of files, and they are fairly big 3Mb to 100Mb.  It causes a lot of GC thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

FileOpen uses [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(VS.85).aspx) in Kernel32.dll. I'm not sure you'll be able to achieve anything more than the .NET framework provides you with, as all the options are already there, unless you perform it as a [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363859(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm fishing through the documentation now.  Do you know if a file opened with CreateFileTransacted, allows for deletion of the parent folder, or are you just suggesting it as an option?

Comment: I assume there's 2 threads working on the file, one to open and another trying to delete at the same time?

Comment: Well ultimately, but I only control one of them.